# Нужен JavaScript или jQuery плагин для валидации формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, npm

Для проекта нужен *client side* плагин для *валидации формы*  желательно чтобы был написан на **JavaScript** или **jQuery** и был *легок в использовании*.

Что посоветуете ?

Comment: В html уже встроена валидация форм, чем не угодила?

Comment: посоветую свою голову, среду разработки и знания JS. А, и еще умение пользоваться гуглом.

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery Validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) **плагин для валидации написанный на jquery**